# Шифрование файлов AES. Проблема с IvParameterSpec при расшифровке

Tags: java, шифрование

Проблема с расшифровкой файла. Соль и IV должны быть статическими.
Шифрование проходит так:

```
private static final byte salt_key[] = new byte[]{5, 9, 7, 2, 6, 3, 1, 8};
private static final byte iv_key[] = new byte[]{5, 9, 7, 2, 6, 3, 1, 8,6,4,1,5,7,6,8,9};

public static void encryptFile(String fileName,String encryptedFileName) 
{
    
    
  FileOutputStream outFile;
  // encrypted file
   // file to be encrypted
  try (FileInputStream inFile = new FileInputStream(fileName))
  {
      outFile = new FileOutputStream(encryptedFileName);
       String password = "javapapers";       
      SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
      KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt_key, 65536,256);
      SecretKey secretKey = factory.generateSecret(keySpec);
      SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), "AES");
      //
      Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
      cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);
      AlgorithmParameters params = cipher.getParameters();
    
    
      //file encryption
      byte[] input = new byte[64];
      int bytesRead;
      while ((bytesRead = inFile.read(input)) != -1)
      {
          byte[] output = cipher.update(input, 0, bytesRead);
          if (output != null)outFile.write(output);
      }
      byte[] output = cipher.doFinal();
      if (output != null) outFile.write(output);
  }
    outFile.flush();
    outFile.close();

    System.out.println("File Encrypted.");
      
}
```

Расшифровка так:

```
public static void decryptFile(String encryptedFileName, String newFileName) 
{
 String password = "javapapers";



 /* byte[] iv;
  // reading the iv
  try(FileInputStream ivFis = new FileInputStream("iv.enc"))
  {
      iv = new byte[16];
      ivFis.read(iv);
      System.out.println("IV: "+iv.toString());
      
      
  }*/
 
  

    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt_key, 65536,256);
    SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(keySpec);
    SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");

    // file decryption
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret, new IvParameterSpec(iv_key));
            FileOutputStream fos;
            
  try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(encryptedFileName))
  {
      fos = new FileOutputStream(newFileName);
      byte[] in = new byte[64];
      int read;
      while ((read = fis.read(in)) != -1)
      {
          byte[] output = cipher.update(in, 0, read);
          if (output != null)fos.write(output);
      }
      byte[] output = cipher.doFinal();
      if (output != null) fos.write(output);
  }
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
    System.out.println("File Decrypted.");  
}
```

Проблема именно в IV. Если, его записывать промежуточно в файл, а потом считывать, то файл расшифровывается нормально. В общем, как сделать его статическим?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена: Не был указан IV при шифровании: Вот так надо:

```
  cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret,new IvParameterSpec(iv_key));
```

Т.е ошибка была в том, что не указал вектор при самом шифровании